# Different Users having same username shows in socket.io & node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am creating chat application in *Node.js and Socket.io*.

it is working fine, but i am facing a little problem.

**Working** (This is what i wants)

1. On one tab User enter his nick name.
2. send message to the connect user with his nick name/
3. On second tab User enter his nick name.
4. send message to the connected users with his name.

**Problem**

When first user connect and send message to the chat, it shows his correct nick name, and when i open another tab, choose nick name, then send message to the chat it send correct message to the chat with his correct nick name.

But when i go to first tab again, and send message at that time message sent but now nick name shows of the second tab user.

*Below is my code, check what i am doing wrong?*

**Client JS**

```js
$(function (){
  var socket = io();
  
  $('#nick-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('new user', $('#user_name').val() ,function(usernames){
     if(usernames){
      $('#username-area').hide();
      $('#chat-area').show();
     }else{
      $('#error_message').html('This username already exists.');
     }
      });
   
   $('#user_name').val('');
  });
  
  socket.on('usernames', function(nicknames){
   var html = '';
   for(i=0; i < nicknames.length;i++){
    html +=nicknames[i] + '<br/>'
   }
   $('#online_users').html(html);
  
  });
  
  
  $('#message-form').submit(function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
   $('#m').val('');
   //return false;
  });
  
  socket.on('new message', function(data){
   console.log(data);
   $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(data.nick +' : '+ data.msg));
  });
  
 })
```

**Server JS**

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var nicknames = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
 
 socket.on('new user', function(get_username, callback){
  if(nicknames.indexOf(get_username) != -1 ){
   callback(false);
  }else{
   callback(true);
   console.log('Username: ', get_username);
   io.nickname = get_username;
   nicknames.push(io.nickname);
   updateNIcknames();
  }
 });
 
 function updateNIcknames(){
  io.emit('usernames', nicknames);
 }
 
 socket.on('chat message', function(data){
  console.log(io.nickname+' : '+data);
  io.emit('new message', {msg:data, nick: io.nickname}); // at here i am sending nickname and message
 });
 
 socket.on('disconnect', function(nickname){
  if(!io.nickname) return;
  console.log('User dissconected ');
  nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(io.nickname),1);
  updateNIcknames();
 });
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('listening on port *:3000');
});
```

Comment: can you share you html code as well

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the server doesn't know who sends the message, so you need to the nickname to the message :

```
$(function (){
    var socket = io();
    var username = "";  // <----- here


    $('#nick-form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            username = $('#user_name').val();
            socket.emit('new user', username ,function(usernames){
                if(usernames){
                    $('#username-area').hide();
                    $('#chat-area').show();
                }else{
                    $('#error_message').html('This username already exists.');
                }
           });

        $('#user_name').val('');
    });

    socket.on('usernames', function(nicknames){
        var html = '';
        for(i=0; i < nicknames.length;i++){
            html +=nicknames[i] + '<br/>'
        }
        $('#online_users').html(html);

    });


    $('#message-form').submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('chat message', {nick: username , msg: $('#m').val()}); // <--- here
        $('#m').val('');
        //return false;
    });

    socket.on('new message', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(data.nick +' : '+ data.msg));
    });

});
```

server :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var nicknames = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('new user', function(get_username, callback){
    if(nicknames.indexOf(get_username) != -1 ){
        callback(false);
    }else{
        callback(true);
        console.log('Username: ', get_username);
        nicknames.push(get_username); // <----- here
        updateNIcknames();
    }
});

function updateNIcknames(){
    io.emit('usernames', nicknames);
}

socket.on('chat message', function(data){
    console.log(data.nick+' : '+data.msg);
    io.emit('new message', {msg:data.msg, nick: data.nick}); // <----- here
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(nickname){
    if(!io.nickname) return;
    console.log('User dissconected ');
    nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(io.nickname),1);
    updateNIcknames();
});
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('listening on port *:3000');
});
```

Comment: I am following this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOSIqJWQkXM but it is working fine, then why my server donot know who sends message?

Comment: @Bougarfaougi I follow what you say, but now it showing not anything, even not a single username. `data.nick` is empty?